# How to start a specific file as Notepad or Word in CMD

Tags: command-line, cmd, command

So I'm trying to start a program as notepad or word, but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: If you want to open notepad from `cmd`  then just type `notepad` and it will open.

Comment: If you want to open any other application then add its path in `system variables`..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I start example.txt as a Notepad or a Word document through cmd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168227/how-to-i-start-example-txt-as-a-notepad-or-a-word-document-through-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

you can write something like

```
C:>notepad
```

or

```
"c:\Program files\MSOffice\World"
```

both call are identic. But path to C:\Windows\notepad.exe is to write in envirinment variable %PATH%.