# How to I start example.txt as a Notepad or a Word document through cmd

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command

Im trying to start a given file as a notepad or a word document, not open a new notepad or word document

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167958/how-to-start-a-specific-file-as-notepad-or-word-in-cmd

Answer (score 2):

```
example.txt
```

or

```
start example.txt
```

or

```
notepad example.txt
```

or

```
start notepad example.txt
```

Comment: How would I open it example.txt as a word document?

Comment: `"c:\path\to\office\word.exe" example.txt`

Answer (score 0):

In cmd, you can just type 'notepad example.txt'.